# OneToMany doesn't create foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE on H2 database

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, jpa-2.1

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE with Hibernate and H2 for integration tests. Below are my entites with unidirectional OneToMany relation. For some reason generated foreign key DDL doesn't contain ON DELETE CASCADE. According to [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#referential_constraint) referential actions are supported. I tried bidirectional OneToMany also but ON DELETE CASCADE is still missing. Please advise. I'd like to avoid using Hibernate specific stuff if possible. Thank you in advance.

My entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DomainObjectLong implements Persistable<Long> {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="ID_GEN" , strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GEN")
    private Long id;

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class EventVO extends DomainObjectLong {
    @Column(name = "time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private EventType type;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
    private List<EventDataVO> data;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "event_data", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"event_id", "key"})
})
public class EventDataVO extends DomainObjectLong {
    @Column(name = "key", length = 128, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "value", length = 512, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String value;
}
```

Properties:

```
datasource.runtime.url=jdbc:h2:mem:runtimetestdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
datasource.runtime.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Log:

```
23:40:44.648 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    alter table event_data 
        add constraint FK_6xxhltyiilvlk02730x7mu7cu 
        foreign key (event_id) 
        references event
Hibernate: 
    alter table event_data 
        add constraint FK_6xxhltyiilvlk02730x7mu7cu 
        foreign key (event_id) 
        references event
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA does not generate ON DELETE CASCADE constraints.

The reason is that the cascading is done on the JPA level with the cascade attribute in the toMany or toOne mapping mapping.

If the database would cascade the delete the state would not match with the persistence context and a delete would be generated by JPA but the database record is already deleted.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So even if I create DDLs myself I should not use  referential actions like ON DELETE CASCADE to avoid possible problem described in your reply, right?

Comment: Exactly. Let Hibernate take control